# What is the most efficient way to store/pass color values (vertex attribute)?

Tags: opengl

Is there a way to store color values on the VRAM other than a float per color component ?

Since color can represented as byte per component, how can I force my  fragment shader to range color component from [0-255] instead of the default range [0.0-1.0]

if I use type as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` , do I have to set *bool normalized* to `GL_TRUE` to convert them to 0.0-1.0 values that can be interpreted by the Fragment shader?

Comment: Look at `glVertexAttribPointer` for the different formats you can use for vertex attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the fragment shader is independent of the input of the vertex shader. For example you are storing colors in RGBA 8 bit format it would look somehting like this.

```
//...
glVertexAttribPointer(  0,4,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,FALSE,4,0);
//...
```

in the vertex shader

```
//the unsigned bytes are automatically converted to floats in the range [0,255]
//if normalized would have been set to true the range would be [0,1]
layout(location = 0) in vec4 color;
out vec4 c;
//...
c = color; //pass color to fragment shader
```

fragment shader

```
in vec4 c;
out vec4 out_color; //output (a texture from a framebuffer)
//....
//the output of the fragment shader must be converted to range [0,1] unless
//you're writing to integer textures (i'm asuming not here)
out_color = c / 255.0f;
```

Comment: Let me get this right, by setting the *normalized* to true, I don't need to do `out_color = c / 255.0f;` , I can just say `out_color = c;`

Comment: Yes, then the it's converted implicitly when passed to  the vertex shader.

Answer (score 1):

A VBO is just a bunch of bytes in the first place. You need to tell OpenGL some information about the data in the VBO. One does that by invoking `glVertexAttribPointer`.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(index, size, GL_FLOAT, ...)
```

Using `GL_FLOAT` OpenGL knows that your data comes in `float32` (4 bytes). In your case, you could use `GL_BYTE` which is an 8 bit number, so you can encode values from 0 to 255.

Since the information is only stored in VAO, one could use the same VBO with different views on data. [Here one can find all available types.](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

Comment: But how can I  use these values in the fragment shader ? I tried to setting out vec4 fColor (in FS) components to values greater than 1 within the range [0,255] .. and it outputs incorrect colors

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of glVertexAttribPointer you have to set the normalize parameter to let the bytes be scaled to the range 0.0 to 1.0.

But as I can see in your comment to another answer, your real problem is with the output. The shader type vec4 contains always of floats to the values must be in range 0.0 to 1.0.